# Laravel VueJs Array's

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and VueJS for my application.

I have a form on the vue instance which allows the user to enter details of an individual and add them to a visit. When added my method adds the details from the inputs to the array of visitors.

> PROBLEM: When I add a visitor to the visitors array and click remove
>   it works great, when I import and click remove on one of the visitors
>   it removes the wrong visitor.

**My vue instance (part)**

```
data: {
  visitor: {},
}
```

**My form**

```
<input v-model="visitor.last" class="input" placeholder="Last Name">
<input v-model="visitor.company" class="input" placeholder="Company">
<input v-model="visitor.email" class="input" placeholder="Email" type="email">
<button class="button is-primary" @click="saveVisitor">Add Visitor</button>
```

**My Method**

```
saveVisitor() {
  this.visitors.push(this.visitor);
  this.visitor = {};
},
```

This all works great and works as it should, I've now added another method for populating the list of Visitors and this is a spreadsheet import which I parse in my Laravel backend and return to my Vue instance.

**METHOD FOR SPREADSHEET**

```
submitImport() {

            const vm = this;

            var form = new FormData();
            form.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0]);

            axios({
              method: 'post',
              url: '/import/visitors',
              data: form
            }).then(function(response){

              if(response.status === 200){

               vm.visitors = response.data;

              } else {

                vm.loading = false;

              }

            });
},
```

When going through the spreadsheet I build up a array in the backend:

**Laravel Controller (part)**

```
$visitor[] = array(
    'first' => $v->FirstName,
    'last' => $v->LastName,
    'email' => $v->Email,
    'company' => $v->Company
);
```

After the function has finished looping through the rows on the spreadsheet my controller returns the array back to the vue instance.

```
return response($visitor,200);
```

I accept the array on my Vue Instance and populate the visitors array on my vue instance with the results.

```
vm.visitors = response.data;
```

And this works great! my only problem is that when I try to remove one of the visitors from the vm.visitors array it removes the wrong one which I'm guessing is due to the keys.

**see my remove method.**

```
removeVisitor(visitor) {
    console.log(visitor);
    //this.visitors.splice(visitor,1);
},
```

When I view the console I get the following, please note I've added some from the spreadsheet import and some via the form inputs.

It looks as though the visitors array on my vue instance has two different types of data.

[image: Screenshot of my image]

When you click the ... in the top object this does return the name etc but this is different from the 2nd object which contains the data clearly?

Comment: Is each visitor getting put in to it's own component?

Comment: Share the code from which the remove visitor method is called.

Comment: share the visitors object state when you try to remove and fails. Also share the removeVisitor parameter visitor what is it

Comment: share the visitors object state when you try to remove and fails. Also share the removeVisitor parameter visitor what is it

Comment: To remove a visitor I pass the whole visitor object.. For example, If I have 10 visitors in the visitors array I would pass just the one visitor I want to remove. I use the this.variable.splice method to remove. It looks as though when I'm storing the visitors from the spreadsheet to the format is different.